# Methods_added for Singleton methods, but not Class methods

Tags: ruby

I'm really not understanding this [Ruby Monk exercise](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/5-metaprogramming-ruby-ascent/chapters/31-lifecycle-hooks/lessons/70-introduction-lifecycle-callbacks):

> There's an important nuance that's worth understanding when dealing with singleton_method_added and method_added.
>
> The most natural tack the mind takes with these two callbacks is to assume that method_added will observe instance methods and singleton_method_added, class methods. This, however, is not entirely true; Ruby's singleton object backs normal objects and contains object specific changes. For classes, these are class methods. But when adding a method to a single, regular object, adding instance methods to that object alone modifies the singleton object for that object.
>
> Let me show you why by having you solve this exercise.

The exercise is:

```
AN_OBJECT = Object.new

def AN_OBJECT.methods_added
  @@methods_added ||= []
end

def AN_OBJECT.singleton_methods_added
  @@singleton_methods_added ||= []
end
```

My attempt was to do this:

```
def AN_OBJECT.methods_added
  unless AN_OBJECT.is_a?(Class)
    @@methods_added ||= []
  end
end

def AN_OBJECT.singleton_methods_added
  if AN_OBJECT.instance_of?(Object)
    @@singleton_methods_added ||= []
  end
end
```

But the specs still fail.

I'm really having trouble wrapping my head around what exactly they want me to do. What is a singleton object? From what I understand, a singleton class is kind of a 'metaclass' that exists solely to give behavior to a certain instance of a class.

Is a singleton object a kind of 'metaobject' that exists solely to give behavior to a certain instance of an object? This is really confusing for me.

Comment: I think it's a typo in the book and should read "singleton class" instead.

Comment: @abustamam Are you able to make the test pass yet?

Comment: No, admittedly I gave up on that specific task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eureka!

```
AN_OBJECT = Object.new

def AN_OBJECT.methods_added
  @@methods_added ||= []
end

def AN_OBJECT.singleton_methods_added
  @@singleton_methods_added ||= []
end

def AN_OBJECT.singleton_method_added(method_name)
  @@singleton_methods_added ||= []
  @@singleton_methods_added << method_name
end
```

If you look at the previous excercise if you scroll up, it should give you enough hint on how to handle it. It's a tragedy that I posted this so much later..

Comment: you don't create a 'def AN_OBJECT.method_added(method_name)' due to the excercise tells us that we don't want to add methods to it.